# DIR recursion doesn't recognize folders beginning with a number

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to replace one image with another in all sub-directories, but the recursive function of DIR (/s) doesn't recognize folders beginning with a number. For example, it would replace the file in the directory "example/image.txt" but not "1234 folder/image.txt"

```
@ECHO off
dir /s /b image.jpg >> FileListing.txt

echo Image replaced in the following folders: >> ImageLocations.txt
for /f %%a in (FileListing.txt) do (
    echo %%a >> ImageLocations.txt
    xcopy /f /q "%CD%\Image.jpg" "%%a"

)
del FileListing.txt
```

Comment: The issue may be the space in the folder name, not the numbers. Try re-running your script with echo on to see exactly what command gets run, and also note any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

`for /f` command, by default, will try to tokenize the input lines using spaces and tabs as delimiters between tokens. If your files/folders have spaces in its names, only the part before the space will be retrieved. To avoid it, disable the line splitting by setting the delimiters to an empty list

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (FileListing.txt) do (
....
```